# `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready` message repeating every minute

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ipv6, kernel

I am using my Linux system for running some serverless functions using OpenFaaS.
I have placed the required invocation command in a shell script and I am constantly running the shell script using a `tmux` session.

I found my system restarting suddenly and abruptly. (I tried inspecting the system while using the GUI through the monitor. The system suddenly freezes and then restarts.) Also, I am using my system through an `ssh` connection. And I find the `ssh` connection to be very unstable. I found these issues happening after a sudden network outrage at the location of my physical machine.

I tried to inspect the kernel logs for a possible reason.

And I found the message :

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

being repeated every minute. I don't know whether it is due to the OpenFaaS function running or something else.

```
...
Aug 19 13:29:28 abhishek kernel: [74108.893026] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 13:32:58 abhishek kernel: [74318.897027] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 13:33:38 abhishek kernel: [74358.860948] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 13:34:18 abhishek kernel: [74398.953078] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 13:34:58 abhishek kernel: [74438.956965] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:43:03 abhishek kernel: [  477.498063] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:43:41 abhishek kernel: [  516.081870] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:43:41 abhishek kernel: [  516.082111] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:43:42 abhishek kernel: [  516.317373] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:44:05 abhishek kernel: [  540.025838] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:44:05 abhishek kernel: [  540.069568] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:44:05 abhishek kernel: [  540.070631] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:44:38 abhishek kernel: [  572.602629] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:45:16 abhishek kernel: [  610.741455] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:45:16 abhishek kernel: [  610.741581] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:45:18 abhishek kernel: [  612.794432] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:45:18 abhishek kernel: [  612.794576] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:45:19 abhishek kernel: [  613.530493] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:46:43 abhishek kernel: [  697.417436] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:46:43 abhishek kernel: [  697.417654] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:46:43 abhishek kernel: [  697.673200] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:46:43 abhishek kernel: [  698.010010] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:46:43 abhishek kernel: [  698.010864] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:49:01 abhishek kernel: [  835.926456] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:49:40 abhishek kernel: [  874.618320] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:58:43 abhishek kernel: [ 1417.501698] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 14:59:23 abhishek kernel: [ 1457.474986] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:00:03 abhishek kernel: [ 1497.449263] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:00:43 abhishek kernel: [ 1537.426682] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:05:43 abhishek kernel: [ 1837.441367] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:06:23 abhishek kernel: [ 1877.509112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:07:03 abhishek kernel: [ 1917.489985] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:07:43 abhishek kernel: [ 1957.445700] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:36:58 abhishek kernel: [ 3712.460997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:37:38 abhishek kernel: [ 3752.525005] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:38:18 abhishek kernel: [ 3792.516960] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:38:48 abhishek kernel: [ 3822.469044] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:44:28 abhishek kernel: [ 4162.441524] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:44:58 abhishek kernel: [ 4192.480977] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:45:38 abhishek kernel: [ 4232.448944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:46:18 abhishek kernel: [ 4272.501008] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:50:13 abhishek kernel: [ 4507.416934] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:50:53 abhishek kernel: [ 4547.440992] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:51:33 abhishek kernel: [ 4587.524846] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:52:13 abhishek kernel: [ 4627.424904] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:54:43 abhishek kernel: [ 4777.476914] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:55:23 abhishek kernel: [ 4817.474553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:56:03 abhishek kernel: [ 4857.556147] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:56:43 abhishek kernel: [ 4897.469687] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:59:13 abhishek kernel: [ 5047.448794] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 15:59:53 abhishek kernel: [ 5087.432895] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:00:33 abhishek kernel: [ 5127.431446] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:01:13 abhishek kernel: [ 5167.461020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:03:28 abhishek kernel: [ 5302.437809] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:03:58 abhishek kernel: [ 5332.432944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:04:28 abhishek kernel: [ 5362.524875] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:05:08 abhishek kernel: [ 5402.537088] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:06:58 abhishek kernel: [ 5512.473155] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:07:38 abhishek kernel: [ 5552.490405] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:08:18 abhishek kernel: [ 5592.521473] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:10:43 abhishek kernel: [ 5737.436895] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:11:23 abhishek kernel: [ 5777.421962] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:12:03 abhishek kernel: [ 5817.500880] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:12:43 abhishek kernel: [ 5857.416818] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:14:28 abhishek kernel: [ 5962.448980] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:15:08 abhishek kernel: [ 6002.473235] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:15:48 abhishek kernel: [ 6042.496937] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:17:43 abhishek kernel: [ 6157.501888] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:18:23 abhishek kernel: [ 6197.452972] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:19:03 abhishek kernel: [ 6237.448836] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:20:28 abhishek kernel: [ 6322.496869] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:21:08 abhishek kernel: [ 6362.440783] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:21:48 abhishek kernel: [ 6402.448743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:23:28 abhishek kernel: [ 6502.500983] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:24:08 abhishek kernel: [ 6542.469255] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:26:13 abhishek kernel: [ 6667.512870] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:26:53 abhishek kernel: [ 6707.500752] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:27:33 abhishek kernel: [ 6747.448880] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:28:58 abhishek kernel: [ 6832.420851] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:29:38 abhishek kernel: [ 6872.485463] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:31:13 abhishek kernel: [ 6967.458116] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:31:53 abhishek kernel: [ 7007.446293] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:33:43 abhishek kernel: [ 7117.441933] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:34:23 abhishek kernel: [ 7157.458390] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:36:13 abhishek kernel: [ 7267.404660] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:36:53 abhishek kernel: [ 7307.424666] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:38:28 abhishek kernel: [ 7402.450438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:39:08 abhishek kernel: [ 7442.532742] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:40:58 abhishek kernel: [ 7552.592685] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:41:38 abhishek kernel: [ 7592.432811] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:42:58 abhishek kernel: [ 7672.448707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:43:38 abhishek kernel: [ 7712.448718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:44:58 abhishek kernel: [ 7792.464797] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:45:38 abhishek kernel: [ 7832.473889] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:47:13 abhishek kernel: [ 7927.481105] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:47:53 abhishek kernel: [ 7967.450173] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:49:13 abhishek kernel: [ 8047.424569] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:49:53 abhishek kernel: [ 8087.424656] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:51:13 abhishek kernel: [ 8167.440791] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:51:53 abhishek kernel: [ 8207.473082] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:53:13 abhishek kernel: [ 8287.414085] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:53:53 abhishek kernel: [ 8327.449703] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:55:13 abhishek kernel: [ 8407.432678] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:56:58 abhishek kernel: [ 8512.444583] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:57:28 abhishek kernel: [ 8542.479356] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:58:58 abhishek kernel: [ 8632.448539] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 16:59:28 abhishek kernel: [ 8662.444607] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:00:43 abhishek kernel: [ 8737.505539] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:02:43 abhishek kernel: [ 8857.426157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:04:28 abhishek kernel: [ 8962.436854] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:06:28 abhishek kernel: [ 9082.488628] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:07:58 abhishek kernel: [ 9172.461901] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:09:43 abhishek kernel: [ 9277.468502] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:11:13 abhishek kernel: [ 9367.505385] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:12:58 abhishek kernel: [ 9472.424784] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:14:28 abhishek kernel: [ 9562.532965] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:16:13 abhishek kernel: [ 9667.504771] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:17:43 abhishek kernel: [ 9757.461439] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:19:28 abhishek kernel: [ 9862.437975] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:20:58 abhishek kernel: [ 9952.429754] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:21:28 abhishek kernel: [ 9982.448627] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:22:28 abhishek kernel: [10042.488770] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:23:58 abhishek kernel: [10132.432581] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:25:28 abhishek kernel: [10222.504576] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:26:43 abhishek kernel: [10297.500512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:28:13 abhishek kernel: [10387.480475] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:29:43 abhishek kernel: [10477.469470] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:31:13 abhishek kernel: [10567.456932] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:32:43 abhishek kernel: [10657.429688] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:34:13 abhishek kernel: [10747.461344] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:35:28 abhishek kernel: [10822.500427] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:36:58 abhishek kernel: [10912.456642] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:38:13 abhishek kernel: [10987.460332] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:39:28 abhishek kernel: [11062.450180] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:40:43 abhishek kernel: [11137.412307] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:41:58 abhishek kernel: [11212.492737] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:43:13 abhishek kernel: [11287.408329] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:44:43 abhishek kernel: [11377.461599] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:45:58 abhishek kernel: [11452.453165] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:47:13 abhishek kernel: [11527.456449] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:48:43 abhishek kernel: [11617.469221] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:49:43 abhishek kernel: [11677.484380] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:50:58 abhishek kernel: [11752.428946] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:52:13 abhishek kernel: [11827.412374] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:53:28 abhishek kernel: [11902.477037] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:54:43 abhishek kernel: [11977.464356] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:55:58 abhishek kernel: [12052.508388] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:56:58 abhishek kernel: [12112.457523] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:58:13 abhishek kernel: [12187.421256] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 17:59:28 abhishek kernel: [12262.448441] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:00:43 abhishek kernel: [12337.444244] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:01:58 abhishek kernel: [12412.466325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:03:13 abhishek kernel: [12487.436437] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:04:13 abhishek kernel: [12547.448236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:05:28 abhishek kernel: [12622.484227] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:06:28 abhishek kernel: [12682.460553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:07:43 abhishek kernel: [12757.456748] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:08:43 abhishek kernel: [12817.445841] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:09:58 abhishek kernel: [12892.488410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:10:58 abhishek kernel: [12952.456923] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:12:13 abhishek kernel: [13027.420401] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:13:13 abhishek kernel: [13087.449614] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:14:28 abhishek kernel: [13162.472763] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:15:28 abhishek kernel: [13222.447070] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:16:28 abhishek kernel: [13282.516290] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:17:28 abhishek kernel: [13342.500507] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:18:43 abhishek kernel: [13417.432403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:19:43 abhishek kernel: [13477.500969] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:20:43 abhishek kernel: [13537.464217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:21:43 abhishek kernel: [13597.420766] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:22:43 abhishek kernel: [13657.516828] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:23:43 abhishek kernel: [13717.444151] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:24:43 abhishek kernel: [13777.426454] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:25:43 abhishek kernel: [13837.417379] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:26:58 abhishek kernel: [13912.424219] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:27:58 abhishek kernel: [13972.424285] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:28:58 abhishek kernel: [14032.464194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:29:58 abhishek kernel: [14092.432185] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:30:58 abhishek kernel: [14152.436019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:31:58 abhishek kernel: [14212.457711] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:32:58 abhishek kernel: [14272.444449] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:33:58 abhishek kernel: [14332.444158] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:34:58 abhishek kernel: [14392.496050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:35:58 abhishek kernel: [14452.457044] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:36:58 abhishek kernel: [14512.468072] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:37:58 abhishek kernel: [14572.420624] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:38:58 abhishek kernel: [14632.440275] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:39:58 abhishek kernel: [14692.404057] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:40:43 abhishek kernel: [14737.416128] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:41:43 abhishek kernel: [14797.435503] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:42:43 abhishek kernel: [14857.488127] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:43:43 abhishek kernel: [14917.428410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:44:28 abhishek kernel: [14962.476059] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:01:58 abhishek kernel: [16012.460029] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:02:43 abhishek kernel: [16057.460090] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:03:43 abhishek kernel: [16117.440147] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:04:43 abhishek kernel: [16177.424178] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:05:28 abhishek kernel: [16222.428582] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:06:28 abhishek kernel: [16282.421743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:07:13 abhishek kernel: [16327.443994] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:08:13 abhishek kernel: [16387.415991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:09:13 abhishek kernel: [16447.431925] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:09:58 abhishek kernel: [16492.451622] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:10:58 abhishek kernel: [16552.463966] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:11:58 abhishek kernel: [16612.488878] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:12:43 abhishek kernel: [16657.463944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Without the `grep` command to filter things out, I have other messages in between these messages:

```
Aug 19 18:30:58 abhishek kernel: [14152.436019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:31:58 abhishek kernel: [14212.457711] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:32:58 abhishek kernel: [14272.444449] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:33:58 abhishek kernel: [14332.444158] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:34:58 abhishek kernel: [14392.496050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:35:01 abhishek CRON[1419159]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 19 18:35:03 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Aug 19 18:35:03 abhishek anacron[1419643]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-08-19
Aug 19 18:35:03 abhishek anacron[1419643]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Aug 19 18:35:03 abhishek systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 19 18:35:58 abhishek kernel: [14452.457044] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:36:32 abhishek systemd[1]: session-10.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 19 18:36:32 abhishek systemd[1]: session-10.scope: Consumed 2.807s CPU time.
Aug 19 18:36:49 abhishek systemd[1]: session-9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 19 18:36:49 abhishek systemd[1]: session-9.scope: Consumed 2.616s CPU time.
Aug 19 18:36:58 abhishek kernel: [14512.468072] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:37:58 abhishek kernel: [14572.420624] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:38:58 abhishek kernel: [14632.440275] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:39:58 abhishek kernel: [14692.404057] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:40:43 abhishek kernel: [14737.416128] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:41:43 abhishek kernel: [14797.435503] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:42:43 abhishek kernel: [14857.488127] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:42:50 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 41 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:43:35 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 42 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:43:43 abhishek kernel: [14917.428410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:44:28 abhishek kernel: [14962.476059] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 18:45:01 abhishek CRON[1488812]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 19 18:45:34 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 44 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:45:37 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 45 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:47:15 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 46 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:47:16 abhishek systemd[1]: session-46.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 19 18:48:20 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 47 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:48:20 abhishek systemd[1]: session-47.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 19 18:52:18 abhishek systemd[1]: session-45.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 19 18:54:07 abhishek systemd[1]: Started Session 48 of User abhishek.
Aug 19 18:55:01 abhishek CRON[1508429]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 19 19:01:58 abhishek kernel: [16012.460029] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:02:43 abhishek kernel: [16057.460090] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:03:43 abhishek kernel: [16117.440147] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:04:43 abhishek kernel: [16177.424178] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:05:01 abhishek CRON[1548607]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 19 19:05:28 abhishek kernel: [16222.428582] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:06:28 abhishek kernel: [16282.421743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:07:13 abhishek kernel: [16327.443994] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:08:13 abhishek kernel: [16387.415991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:09:13 abhishek kernel: [16447.431925] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:09:58 abhishek kernel: [16492.451622] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:10:58 abhishek kernel: [16552.463966] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:11:58 abhishek kernel: [16612.488878] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:12:43 abhishek kernel: [16657.463944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:13:43 abhishek kernel: [16717.436100] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:14:43 abhishek kernel: [16777.412157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:15:01 abhishek CRON[1620728]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 19 19:15:43 abhishek kernel: [16837.415870] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:16:28 abhishek kernel: [16882.415877] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 19 19:17:01 abhishek CRON[1635207]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Can anyone let me know what possibly might be causing this issue? What does this message mean? And possible ways of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

It means the *actual Ethernet link* is being lost, then re-established, every minute.

It's most likely the same issue that caused the earlier network outage – normally I would say either your machine's physical Ethernet interface is dying, or the switch that it's connected to, or possibly even the cable connecting them is broken. Though if even the local console keeps freezing, it may be something different.

The kernel IPv6 module is a bit verbose about link establishment, but this does not in any way imply that the IPv6 module *causes* it.